# How to remove an extra char which is coming in XMLAGG() output

Tags: oracle11g

Im using Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production

We replaced LISTAGG() with XMLAGG() to avoid concatenation error.
when i check the lenght of charecters from both of the fuction output, XMLAGG() giving an extra char in length.
Could you please suggest me how can i overcome this issue.

Please find the below sql and out put

XMLAGG():

```
SELECT TO_CHAR (
      SUBSTR (
         XMLAGG (XMLELEMENT (e, table_name, CHR (13)).EXTRACT (
                    '//text()') ORDER BY tablespace_name).GetClobVal (),
         1,
         2000))
      AS str_concate,
   LENGTH (
      TO_CHAR (
         SUBSTR (
            XMLAGG (XMLELEMENT (e, table_name, CHR (13)).EXTRACT (
                       '//text()') ORDER BY tablespace_name).GetClobVal (),
            1,
            2000)))
      AS str_length
FROM all_tables
WHERE table_name = 'TEST_LOAD
```

OUTPUT:

```
STR_CONCATE                  STR_LENGTH

TEST_LOAD  TEST_LOAD              26
```

LISTAGG()

```
SELECT LISTAGG (SUBSTR (table_name, 1, 2000), CHR (13))
      WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY tablespace_name)
      AS str_concate,
   LENGTH (
      LISTAGG (SUBSTR (table_name, 1, 2000), CHR (13))
         WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY tablespace_name))
      AS str_length
FROM all_tables
WHERE table_name = 'TEST_LOAD';
```

OUTPUT:

```
STR_CONCATE                  STR_LENGTH

TEST_LOAD TEST_LOAD               25
```

Comment: Replace CHR(13) with some other character and run the query. You will see that in XMLAGG, that character is appended at the end, while in LISTAGG it is not.

Comment: Same CHR(13) i have in LISTAGG() also, but its not giving any problem

Comment: I suppose @Eat Å Peach proposed to replace chr(13) with another (visible) character to show you that XMLAGG adds this separator after each table_name (even after the last)

Comment: yes i removed CHR(13) and checked with ','
then i used rtrim(...., ',') to eliminate the last one. Where as samething is not working with chr(13) :(

Answer (score 1):

- In case of `XMLELEMENT`, you actually create node of XML tree with two children: `table_name` and `CHR(13)`. (May be it finally looks like single node since both are texts but it is not important.) It is [expansion of `value_expr` nonterminal](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions220.htm).  The substantial thing is the node is not aware of other nodes and `CHR(13)` is added to every node as its suffix or, in other words, *terminator*.
- In case of `LISTAGG`, you describe aggregation of multiple elements. In this case, your `CHR(13)` serves as [`delimiter` (see syntax diagram)](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions089.htm#SQLRF30030) which is put between elements. It is *separator* rather than terminator.

Since `XMLAGG` does not suffer with [4000 char limit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29776515/653539), I usually prefer `XMLAGG`.
If *separator* is needed, I recommend to prepend it before each value and cut first occurence using `substr`. Appending after is possible but makes expression harder.

```sql
substr(
  xmlagg(
    xmlelement(e, ', ' || table_name).extract('//text()')
    order by tablespace_name
  ).getclobval(),
  3   -- length(', ')+1
)
```

Comment: You can also use LTRIM or RTRIM