# Oracle - ORA-01489: result of string concatenation is too long

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, size, listagg

Created one view within which one field(of 6) is a concatenation of two fields from the source table.  Created a second view that uses listagg to potentially combine the results of the concatenation.  Using this two step operation correctly returns the listagg concatenation of the two fields from the source table.

When I try to create one view that will both produce the concatenation and the listagg, I get the oracle error ora-01489 Result of string concatenation is too long.

As a test, I selected max(length(concatenated field) and that returned 837.  So the stated error is in error, it seems.

So it must be in the syntax.  I have tried rtrim, trim and even substr, but cannot get the view statement to both compile listagg(concatenation) and return data.

That I am able to develop the two views that correctly return the data suggests I have the basic syntax down, but the task of combining the concatenation with the listagg function I have not been able to figure out.

In a separate situation, I have been able to combine the concatenation with the listagg function in one statement:

```
    LISTAGG (STATEMENTS || ' - ' || BIRTH_DATE, ';  ')
                   WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY STATEMENTS || ' - ' || BIRTH_DATE)
                   AS GROWING_UP
```

This syntax correctly returns the desired data.........

But in the situation described above, similar syntax creates the Ora-01489 error.

Knowing that at times Oracle errors can be misleading, I am wondering if any onboard experts might know of any reason other than that stated that Oracle might throw this error?

```
LISTAGG ((NUMBER || '-' || text), ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY (NUMBER || '-' || text))
AS
  restrictions FROM source
```

returns the error

Comment: Why you didn't test SUM(length(concatenated field)) ? :)

Comment: Sum is different to max though; the longest length of a single concatenated field is 837, but that doesn't tell you how long the listagg of several of those individual concatenated fields might be. Which I think is what the OP is having trouble with. Would be useful to a SQL Fiddle that reproduces this, or at least the code that produces the error - not just code that works.

Comment: max is reading the listagg(concatenated) field, so that should be as long as any one concatenated listagg(ed) field will be.

Comment: edited the original post

Comment: Your phrasing is misleading then, "listagg to ... combine the results of the concatenation" sounds like your max is for the inner bit, not the combined string. You know what you mean but we don't necessarily. You still aren't showing the whole code, of the two views that work and the bit that doesn't. Based on what you've said I'd guess you've got your grouping wrong in the combined version. Can't really help you without all the information though.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You are exceeding the **SQL limit** of 4000 bytes which applies to `LISTAGG` as well.

```
SQL> SELECT listagg(text, ',') WITHIN GROUP (
  2  ORDER BY NULL)
  3  FROM
  4    (SELECT to_char(to_date(level,'j'), 'jsp') text FROM dual CONNECT BY LEVEL < 250
  5    )
  6  /
SELECT listagg(text, ',') WITHIN GROUP (
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01489: result of string concatenation is too long
```

As a workaround, you could use **XMLAGG**.

For example,

```
SQL> SET LONG 2000000
SQL> SET pagesize 50000
SQL> SELECT rtrim(xmlagg(XMLELEMENT(e,text,',').EXTRACT('//text()')
  2                     ).GetClobVal(),',') very_long_text
  3  FROM
  4    (SELECT to_char(to_date(level,'j'), 'jsp') text FROM dual CONNECT BY LEVEL < 250
  5    )
  6  /

VERY_LONG_TEXT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
one,two,three,four,five,six,seven,eight,nine,ten,eleven,twelve,thirteen,fourteen
,fifteen,sixteen,seventeen,eighteen,nineteen,twenty,twenty-one,twenty-two,twenty
-three,twenty-four,twenty-five,twenty-six,twenty-seven,twenty-eight,twenty-nine,
thirty,thirty-one,thirty-two,thirty-three,thirty-four,thirty-five,thirty-six,thi
rty-seven,thirty-eight,thirty-nine,forty,forty-one,forty-two,forty-three,forty-f
our,forty-five,forty-six,forty-seven,forty-eight,forty-nine,fifty,fifty-one,fift
y-two,fifty-three,fifty-four,fifty-five,fifty-six,fifty-seven,fifty-eight,fifty-
nine,sixty,sixty-one,sixty-two,sixty-three,sixty-four,sixty-five,sixty-six,sixty
-seven,sixty-eight,sixty-nine,seventy,seventy-one,seventy-two,seventy-three,seve
nty-four,seventy-five,seventy-six,seventy-seven,seventy-eight,seventy-nine,eight
y,eighty-one,eighty-two,eighty-three,eighty-four,eighty-five,eighty-six,eighty-s
even,eighty-eight,eighty-nine,ninety,ninety-one,ninety-two,ninety-three,ninety-f
our,ninety-five,ninety-six,ninety-seven,ninety-eight,ninety-nine,one hundred,one
 hundred one,one hundred two,one hundred three,one hundred four,one hundred five
,one hundred six,one hundred seven,one hundred eight,one hundred nine,one hundre
d ten,one hundred eleven,one hundred twelve,one hundred thirteen,one hundred fou
rteen,one hundred fifteen,one hundred sixteen,one hundred seventeen,one hundred
eighteen,one hundred nineteen,one hundred twenty,one hundred twenty-one,one hund
red twenty-two,one hundred twenty-three,one hundred twenty-four,one hundred twen
ty-five,one hundred twenty-six,one hundred twenty-seven,one hundred twenty-eight
,one hundred twenty-nine,one hundred thirty,one hundred thirty-one,one hundred t
hirty-two,one hundred thirty-three,one hundred thirty-four,one hundred thirty-fi
ve,one hundred thirty-six,one hundred thirty-seven,one hundred thirty-eight,one
hundred thirty-nine,one hundred forty,one hundred forty-one,one hundred forty-tw
o,one hundred forty-three,one hundred forty-four,one hundred forty-five,one hund
red forty-six,one hundred forty-seven,one hundred forty-eight,one hundred forty-
nine,one hundred fifty,one hundred fifty-one,one hundred fifty-two,one hundred f
ifty-three,one hundred fifty-four,one hundred fifty-five,one hundred fifty-six,o
ne hundred fifty-seven,one hundred fifty-eight,one hundred fifty-nine,one hundre
d sixty,one hundred sixty-one,one hundred sixty-two,one hundred sixty-three,one
hundred sixty-four,one hundred sixty-five,one hundred sixty-six,one hundred sixt
y-seven,one hundred sixty-eight,one hundred sixty-nine,one hundred seventy,one h
undred seventy-one,one hundred seventy-two,one hundred seventy-three,one hundred
 seventy-four,one hundred seventy-five,one hundred seventy-six,one hundred seven
ty-seven,one hundred seventy-eight,one hundred seventy-nine,one hundred eighty,o
ne hundred eighty-one,one hundred eighty-two,one hundred eighty-three,one hundre
d eighty-four,one hundred eighty-five,one hundred eighty-six,one hundred eighty-
seven,one hundred eighty-eight,one hundred eighty-nine,one hundred ninety,one hu
ndred ninety-one,one hundred ninety-two,one hundred ninety-three,one hundred nin
ety-four,one hundred ninety-five,one hundred ninety-six,one hundred ninety-seven
,one hundred ninety-eight,one hundred ninety-nine,two hundred,two hundred one,tw
o hundred two,two hundred three,two hundred four,two hundred five,two hundred si
x,two hundred seven,two hundred eight,two hundred nine,two hundred ten,two hundr
ed eleven,two hundred twelve,two hundred thirteen,two hundred fourteen,two hundr
ed fifteen,two hundred sixteen,two hundred seventeen,two hundred eighteen,two hu
ndred nineteen,two hundred twenty,two hundred twenty-one,two hundred twenty-two,
two hundred twenty-three,two hundred twenty-four,two hundred twenty-five,two hun
dred twenty-six,two hundred twenty-seven,two hundred twenty-eight,two hundred tw
enty-nine,two hundred thirty,two hundred thirty-one,two hundred thirty-two,two h
undred thirty-three,two hundred thirty-four,two hundred thirty-five,two hundred
thirty-six,two hundred thirty-seven,two hundred thirty-eight,two hundred thirty-
nine,two hundred forty,two hundred forty-one,two hundred forty-two,two hundred f
orty-three,two hundred forty-four,two hundred forty-five,two hundred forty-six,t
wo hundred forty-seven,two hundred forty-eight,two hundred forty-nine
```

---

If you want to **concatenate multiple columns** which itself have **4000 bytes**, then you can concatenate the XMLAGG output of each column to avoid the SQL limit of 4000 bytes.

For example,

```
WITH DATA AS
  ( SELECT 1 id, rpad('a1',4000,'*') col1, rpad('b1',4000,'*') col2 FROM dual
  UNION
  SELECT 2 id, rpad('a2',4000,'*') col1, rpad('b2',4000,'*') col2 FROM dual
  )
SELECT ID,
       rtrim(xmlagg(XMLELEMENT(e,col1,',').EXTRACT('//text()') ).GetClobVal(), ',')
       || 
       rtrim(xmlagg(XMLELEMENT(e,col2,',').EXTRACT('//text()') ).GetClobVal(), ',') 
       AS very_long_text
FROM DATA
GROUP BY ID
ORDER BY ID;
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I may have to go xml... I was hoping to stay in varchar2, especially since I know no field will exceed the 837 length.

Comment: @user761758 You don't have to make any changes to the table(or schema). All you need to do is, implement my suggestion, replace the table_name with your table_name in the example. That's it. Please mark it answered, it would help others.

Comment: as you stated, your reply suggests a workaround, but it does not actually answer the original question as to why Oracle returned the error in the first place.  I would like to see if anyone might know why the error was returned when we know the resulting data will not come close to exceeding the 4000 character limit..

Comment: @user761758 Not sure if you have tested, but, `MAX` and `SUM` are different. Could you please confirm if you have tested it?

Comment: sum length did return way over 4000, but is that not summing all the fields within the view, not just one field? no one field exceeds the 4000, but added together they do, of course....... I am reading the fields from a view that has the listagg(concatenated) fields... the data is there, I am just trying to do it in one step not two, but the desired results are in the view I am testing.

Comment: @ lalit : can u help on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72413894/ora-01489-result-of-string-concatenation-is-too-long-in-oracle