# Oracle SQL query CONCAT, GROUP BY

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

I have this table

[image]

I wanted to sort by POS `ASC` and also aggregate the two columns X,Y so that my ID becomes Unique. So the result should be like this.

[image]

I tried for many hours and I could aggregate the column X,Y. But when I'm doing a `GROUP BY` ID and then `WMCONCAT(X,Y)` I couldn't sort it by the POS col....

Any help maybe..? Thanks.

Comment: Please can  you provide the SQL you are trying, so any errors you are getting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `WM_CONCAT`, try using the [`LISTAGG`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions089.htm) aggregate function: it allows you to specify an ordering of your choice:

```
SELECT ID,  
       LISTAGG('(' || X || ', ' || Y || ')', ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY POS) AS XY
FROM tab
GROUP BY ID
```

Check the demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/-nnLf9Z1).

Comment: It works. But not for my table... I got error ORA-04189, it seems like that the string is too long.

Do you have any solution for this? Since VARCHAR 4000 is maximum size.
@lemon

Comment: Check here >> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29776035/oracle-ora-01489-result-of-string-concatenation-is-too-long.